# Is there a way of setting an ECR image as a build artifact in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I am working with Azure DevOps build and release pipelines to deploy a containerised .NET Core application. Previously, the image repo has been Docker Hub and the deployment system has been an on-premise Kubernetes cluster. However, now we are shifting to AWS, and we're looking at using ECR and EKS.

In my current pipelines, the build pipeline builds and pushes the container image to Docker Hub, and the release pipeline uses the DockerHub image artifact as its source, which all works nicely.

However, while there is an ECR build step in the Azure marketplace, I can't see a way of setting up ECR as an artifact source. Has anyone been able to solve this? Or should I just package up the DLLs and JSON settings as a build artifact, and then have a Dockerfile that takes those files and builds the image at the start of the release step (so I still am deploying a single image and then promoting to different environments)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify actually any artifact here. What you actually should do is build Docker image and then push it to ECR. Later on deployment stages you just need to reuse that image. [Here](https://www.devguides.dev/how-to-build-and-deploy-docker-images-from-azure-devops-to-aws-ecr/) is a good tutorial how to push image to ECR:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: dev
  - name: DOCKER_REPOSITORY
    value: $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com/$(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME)

steps:
- script: |
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION) | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build docker image
  inputs:
    repository: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY)
    command: buildAndPush
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags: |
      latest
```

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof, I can do that part of the process without issue - it's the taking the image from ECR as an artifact that I have problems with, because Azure doesn't have an ECR artifact provider, whereas it does have a provider for Docker Hub (and ACR, of course).

Comment: What do you mean by docker provider? ECR service connection?

Comment: I mean that if you create a release pipeline in Azure Devops, you have a choice of a number of artifacts that your pipeline can depend on, such as source repositories, Azure artifacts, and more importantly for my question, DockerHub and ACR. But there is no equivalent for ECR, presumably because one hasn't been written, although there is an ECR step for publishing an image _to_ the ECR. So presumably someone would need to write a plugin for Azure DevOps that implements a Microsoft-specified interface, that would allow me to take ECR directly as an artifact

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?